# Paging of multi-dimensional array returns unreliable results

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, paging

I have created a function to display a multi-dimensional array (from a DB table) arranged by the parent id (pid). I need to add paging ability, but when I add "LIMIT $offset, $recsperpage" to my SELECT query, I get unreliable results. There are 14 records in my test DB, with LIMIT $recsperpage set to 10 it only shows the parent items.

For example, without LIMIT the results are:

```
Home
About Us
  Our History
    Our Founders
  Our Clients
Faq
Services
  Corporate Services
  Property Services
  Employment Services
  Foundation Services
  Licensing Services
  Tax Services
Contact Us
```

With $recsperpage set to 10, the results on page 1 are:

```
Home
About Us
Services
```

Then on page 2:

```
Contact
```

My sub-pages are missing.  To make matters worse, if I set $recsperpage to 6 I get the same results on pages 1 & 2, but then on page 3 I get an error "Undefined offset: 1" which points to the function call (as shown below).  I'm really stumped and I could use some help.

Here is my query:

```
    mysqli_select_db($isiteadmin, $database_isiteadmin);
    $query_getText = "SELECT page_id, pid, page_name, link_name, headline, deck, ordr FROM webtext ORDER BY pid, ordr LIMIT $offset, $recsperpage";
    $getText = mysqli_query($isiteadmin, $query_getText) or die('Sorry, could not connect to database.');
    $row_getText = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getText);
```

Here is my array construction:

```
    // Initialize the storage array:
    $pagelist = array();

    while (list($page_id, $pid, $page_name, $link_name, $headline, $deck, $ordr ) = mysqli_fetch_array($getText, MYSQL_BOTH)) {

    // Add to the array:
    $pagelist[$pid][$page_id] = array('pgid'=>$page_id,'pid'=>$pid, 'pgname'=>$page_name, 'linkn'=>$link_name,'hdline'=>$headline,'deck'=>$deck,'ordr'=>$ordr );
    }
```

Here is the call to the function:

```
    // Send the first array element
    // to the make_list() function:
    make_list($pagelist[1]);
```

Here is the function:

```
    function make_list ($parent, $depth = 0) {

    // Need the main $pagelist array plus other variables used within this function:
    global $pagelist, $counter, $contentdir, $pid;

    // Loop through each limited subarray:
    foreach ($parent as $pid=>$item) {          

    // Display the item:
?>  
    <tr class="pglist <?php if (isset($pagelist[$pid])) { echo 'haschild'; } else { echo ''; } ?> <?php if ($counter++ % 2) {echo 'hilite';} ?> <?php echo 'T' . $depth; ?>">
    <td class="pgname "><?php if ((!isset($pagelist[$pid])) && ($item['pid'] == 1)) { echo $item['pgname']; } // category page without decendents
                                if ((isset($pagelist[$pid])) && ($item['pid'] == 1)) { echo '* ' . $item['pgname']; } // category page with decendents
                                    if ((isset($pagelist[$pid])) && ($item['pid'] != 1)) { echo '<span class="el">&nbsp;L *</span> ' . $item['pgname']; } // child page with decendents
                                        if ((!isset($pagelist[$pid])) && ($item['pid'] != 1)) { echo '<span class="el">&nbsp;L</span> ' . $item['pgname']; } // child page without decendents ?></td>
    <td class="hdline"><?php echo $item['hdline']; ?></td>
    <td class="deck"><?php echo $item['deck']; ?></td>
    <td class="order"><?php echo $item['ordr']; ?></td>      
    </tr>
<?php

    // Check for sub-items:
    if (isset($pagelist[$pid])) { 

        // Call this function:
        make_list($pagelist[$pid], $depth = ($depth + 1));

        $depth = ($depth - 1);

            } // End check for subitems

          } // End of FOREACH loop.

        } // End of make_list() function.
```

Here is a var_dump of the array:

```
    Array
    (
    [1] => Array
    (
        [2] => Array
            (
                [pgid] => 2
                [pid] => 1
                [pgname] => Home
                [linkn] => home
                [hdline] => This is the headline for the home page
                [deck] => 
                [ordr] => 1
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [pgid] => 3
                [pid] => 1
                [pgname] => About Us
                [linkn] => about
                [hdline] => This is the headline for About Us
                [deck] => 
                [ordr] => 2
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [pgid] => 6
                [pid] => 1
                [pgname] => Service Areas
                [linkn] => practice
                [hdline] => This is the Service Areas page headline
                [deck] => 
                [ordr] => 4
            )

        [21] => Array
            (
                [pgid] => 21
                [pid] => 1
                [pgname] => Contact Us
                [linkn] => contact
                [hdline] => Contact Us
                [deck] => 
                [ordr] => 99
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [10] => Array
            (
                [pgid] => 10
                [pid] => 3
                [pgname] => Our History
                [linkn] => history
                [hdline] => This is the Our History page headline
                [deck] => 
                [ordr] => 1
            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [pgid] => 11
                [pid] => 3
                [pgname] => Our Clients
                [linkn] => clients
                [hdline] => This is the Our Clients page headline
                [deck] => 
                [ordr] => 2
            )

        [12] => Array
            (
                [pgid] => 12
                [pid] => 3
                [pgname] => FAQ
                [linkn] => faq
                [hdline] => Frequently Asked Questions
                [deck] => 
                [ordr] => 3
            )

    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [7] => Array
            (
                [pgid] => 7
                [pid] => 6
                [pgname] => Corporate Services
                [linkn] => corporate
                [hdline] => This is the Corporate Services page headline
                [deck] => 
                [ordr] => 1
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [pgid] => 9
                [pid] => 6
                [pgname] => Property Services
                [linkn] => intellectual
                [hdline] => This is the Property Services page headline
                [deck] => 
                [ordr] => 2
            )

        [13] => Array
            (
                [pgid] => 13
                [pid] => 6
                [pgname] => Employment Services
                [linkn] => employment
                [hdline] => This is the Employment Services page headline
                [deck] => 
                [ordr] => 4
            )

        [14] => Array
            (
                [pgid] => 14
                [pid] => 6
                [pgname] => Foundation Services
                [linkn] => formation
                [hdline] => This is the Foundation Services page headline
                [deck] => 
                [ordr] => 5
            )

        [15] => Array
            (
                [pgid] => 15
                [pid] => 6
                [pgname] => Licensing Services
                [linkn] => contracts
                [hdline] => This is the Licensing Services page headline
                [deck] => 
                [ordr] => 6
            )

        [16] => Array
            (
                [pgid] => 16
                [pid] => 6
                [pgname] => Tax Services
                [linkn] => tax
                [hdline] => This is the Tax Services page headline
                [deck] => 
                [ordr] => 7
            )

    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [41] => Array
            (
                [pgid] => 41
                [pid] => 10
                [pgname] => Our Founders
                [linkn] => founders
                [hdline] => Our Founders
                [deck] => This is info about our company founders.
                [ordr] => 1
            )

    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [18] => Array
            (
                [pgid] => 18
                [pid] => 17
                [pgname] => News Stories
                [linkn] => news
                [hdline] => News Stories
                [deck] => 
                [ordr] => 1
            )

        [19] => Array
            (
                [pgid] => 19
                [pid] => 17
                [pgname] => Upcoming Events
                [linkn] => events
                [hdline] => Upcoming Events
                [deck] => 
                [ordr] => 2
            )

      )

)
```

Comment: If your record set is not likely to be huge then grab the whole lot in SQL, put the result in your session and paginate using array functions

Comment: What is huge, hundreds?

Comment: Yeah hundreds would be no probs. Millions might start to give memory related headache. Others may have opinion on this  but in my experience for what you have shown easier to manipulate a PHP array